# Dialogflow CX - Required Page Parameters problem

Tags: parameters, required, dialogflow-cx

I'm creating a flow in Dialogflow CX and I faced a problem with the pages Parameters.

When I read about it, it says that when you check the required checkbox, the parameter must be filled before the conversation can move to another page. But in reality, if you create a Route with condition and the condition is true (any-variable-name = null as example), then the flow move to the other page even if the Required parameter is not filled.

I have to use (any-variable-name = null AND $page.params.status = "FINAL") to assure that the page will not move until the parameter is filled.

Anyone can explain why the Required checkbox just don't stop the page to move?
Else it's useless to set Required. I also test with 2 parameters, one Required and the second no. Using the $page.params.status = "FINAL" the page doesn't change until the two parameters are filled.

I'm confused.
Can anyone can help me to understand that?